# Getting FK set from given QuerySet

Tags: python, django

Using django, I'm trying to get a QuerySet of FK relationships from another QuerySet.

That is, given a relation like so:
`ParentTable (ParentID)` and 
`ChildTable(ChildID, ParentID`

I have a particular QuerySet
`children = Child.objects.filter(**some_filters)`
and I need a QuerySet for the `Parent` objects "referenced" in the `children` QuerySet.

My initial thought was to use only, like so:
`Parent.objects.filter(id__in=child.only('parent'))`, but inspecting the SQL query shows that gives a WHERE clause along the lines of `ParentID IN (SELECT subq.ChildID FROM ...` which obviously yields undesired results. (inspection of the only method shows my use here is incorrect, so this behaviour is expected)

The desired query would be something `ParentID IN (SELECT subq.ParentID FROM ...`

Comment: `Parent.objects.filter(child__in=children)` seems to work, but I'm not exactly sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have answered your question:

Consider this, when create a Foreign Key reference then, Django automatically creates a reverse reference for you which is why you are able to filter results based on the child. Moreover, if you want to abide this behavior you can use Symmetrical=False kwargs in the Model Field to not generate the reverse relationship.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
...

class Child(models.Model):
     parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

## You can always make the query:

```
Parent.objects.filter(child__in = Childrens.objects.all())
```